# Configure lock on suspend

Tags: suspend, lightdm, lock-screen

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my laptop (Dell XPS 13 but I don't think it matters here). When waking it up from suspend, by closing/opening the lid or `systemctl suspend`, I get the locking screen of lightdm. But I'm not able to find where this behavior is defined !

I tried looking in various conf files (`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, the `pm-utils` conf files) without any success. I'm interested in changing this default behaviour to execute my custom lock program (basically i3lock) on wake up. I tried to launch the custom lock before suspending: on wake I have to enter my password for my custom lock first, then it launches the lightdm lockscreen for which I have to enter my password once again.k

So my question is: where is located the configuration file that defines the lock system used on suspend/wake ?

(If that matters, I'm not running any DE, just i3 as a WM.)

Comment: I think it should be under power settings

Comment: @AndreasHartmann What do you mean "under power settings" ? I'm looking for the file that defines the locker used on suspend/wake up. (I'm not running Unity or Gnome, so GUI configuration panel from those are not an option.)